# Detect sleep event or wake up event in UWP application

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10-universal

How to detect sleep or wake up event in UWP application. We tried `Suspending` and `Resuming` events but none of them are working apart from manually Debugging/Calling  from Visual Studio events.

**Update**
using `extendedExecutionUnconstrained` capability preventing `Suspending` and `Resuming`

Comment: Do you mean system sleep/wake power management events?

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT yes, i have some different tasks that needs to done on both.

Answer (score 0):

Suspending and Resuming are the right events to listen to. Just tested it in a UWP app to double-check.

Be sure to test without debugger attached because the debugger will prevent your app from actually getting suspended.

Comment: Tried with new blank UWP app its working fine there, Do you have any idea what can be the reason why these events are not firing for my app. Any configuration that need to be reconfigured or something like that.

Comment: Two possible reasons come to mind:
1) you are using an ExtendedExecutionSession (which would prevent it from being suspended)
2) you are using in-proc background tasks or an in-proc AppService (which may also prevent your app from getting suspended)

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.suspending) `Suspending` event can fire even when App losses focus. How can we know that this is system sleep or just the app was switched to background? Or are you guys talking about different event?

Comment: @miradham You are correct that the app can be suspended for different reason and there is currently no way to distinguish between the suspending reasons. However, I would argue you want to run your full state preservation code in all cases, because once you are suspended you may get terminated down the road and not get a chance to respond to other events anymore. Think about this: user minimizes your app so it gets suspended. Later the system goes to sleep. So you should have run your state preservation code at the moment you got minimized because that's the last moment you got to run any code

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT just another question... are you aware if those events are available from Desktop bridge? Using `C++/WinRT` I tried to reach them from Win32 App which is wrapped into Desktop bridge, I could compile my code, but not getting actual events

Comment: @miradham You mean Suspending/Resuming events? Those do not apply to desktop bridge applications. If you want system sleep/wake events in desktop bridge apps you should use the native Win32 events.